# Programmatically determine whether a Youtube video has been taken down

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm getting most of the music on [Rap Exegesis](http://rapexegesis.com/) from YouTube (in the form of embedded players). Unfortunately, there's always the risk that one of the videos I'm using will be taken down (due to copyright issues or whatever), thereby breaking the corresponding page on my site.

Ideally I would have a cronjob that would check (nightly say) whether any videos had been removed and notify me. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Comment: I haven't had the chance to set this up yet, but when I do I'll probably go with @Jakobud's hacky CURL solution (I don't want to read any API documentation)

Comment: fair enough. what language are you doing this in? it likely that the API route is just as succinct as the cURL route if not more so and certainly will be more accurate

Comment: Ruby (on Rails) -- yeah, maybe I'll give the API route a closer look

Comment: theres some code here that might help http://www.quarkruby.com/2008/1/15/activeresource-and-youtube

Answer (score 14):

The information you need is available via the [YouTube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html), specifically in the [yt:state tag](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:state)

Depending what language you are programming in there is lots of code around for interacting with the YouTube API.

Post here with more details if you are still having issues getting this to work.

Comment: To be specific, you have to look for the yt:state tag in the XML document located at "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/#{video_id}"

Comment: Actually this doesn't work -- for example, this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MX6rC1krGp0 plays & embeds fine, and yet the corresponding feed (http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/MX6rC1krGp0) has this <yt:state> tag: `<yt:state name='restricted' reasonCode='limitedSyndication'>Syndication of this video was restricted by its owner.</yt:state>`

Answer (score 4):

As well as the "yt:state tag", the OP of the video may not allow it to be embedded. If the list of songs on the front page is coming from a playlist that you maintain on YouTube, for example, then a way to make sure you aren't getting songs that aren't embeddable is to include the "&format=5" parameter when retrieving your list. E.g.

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/8BCDD04DE8F771B2?v=2&format=5

Also, if you are worried about country-level restrictions, then use the "&restriction=[two-letter country code]" parameter.

See the '[Developer's Guide: Data API Protocol – API Query Parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers%5Fguide%5Fprotocol%5Fapi%5Fquery%5Fparameters.html)'.

Answer (score 1):

A hacky way to do it would be to use CURL to get the html of the page/video you are wondering about, and then look for the error-box DIV that shows up at the top that says the video has been removed. If it exists and its visible, the video has probably been removed.

Hacky, but I betcha it would work.

Comment: Well, it would work today.  But don't build something that relies on a div tag unless YouTube says that you can trust it.  It seems too easy for that to change.  I'd definitely recommend using the API instead.

Comment: I definitely agree. Just wanted to throw out another option, even though its a total hack.

Answer (score 0):

As @seengee says, the "right" way to do this is to look for the [yt:state](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube%5Fdata%5Fapi%5Ftag%5Fyt%3Astate) tag in the XML representation of a YouTube video via the YouTube API

To get this XML representation, you GET `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID` ([more details here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Retrieve_video_entry)). So implementing this check should be as easy as:

```
def valid_embed_link?
  doc = Hpricot(open("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/#{youtube_video_id}"))
  doc.at('yt:state').blank?
end
```

Unfortunately this yields false positives. For example, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MX6rC1krGp0 plays fine, but http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/MX6rC1krGp0 contains a `yt:state` tag. Therefore, I've gone with this hackier method:

```
def valid_embed_link?
  doc = Hpricot(open("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=#{youtube_video_id}"))
  return doc.at('.yt-alert-content').blank?
end
```