# How to detect blocked youtube videos through javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube

How to detect if a youtube video is not playable?

I am aware there is a way by calling a request to the youtube api however this would take too much time to check for each video since the videos are playing on user request.

Is there a way to check on the status of the youtube player and if it does not play then act accordingly?

I know there a few status like ready, stopped, playing, qued. Couldnt find a status for this specific thing.

Thanks in advance

ok I have found the solution. But it wouldnt let me post it because im not cool enough like you guys. Here it is:

```
onYouTubePlayerReady = function() {
    player.addEventListener("onError", "onPlayerError");
}

function onPlayerError(errorCode) {
    playnext();
}
```

if you want to check for a certain error the error codes are on the youtube site. However this was enough for me.

Comment: `Is there a way to check on the status of the youtube player and if it does not play then act accordingly?` -- That would almost certainly take longer (and be more complicated) than simply checking the YouTube API.

Comment: It shouldnt. I am looking now into the on error event. I think it might be the solution.

Comment: Can you provide any blocked videos for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by 'blocked' you mean removed by the user, or removed because of copyright infringement, then your answer will be in [this thread…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591293/programmatically-determine-whether-a-youtube-video-has-been-taken-down).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you did it but I did it like this:

```
    ...

    events{
         ...
         'onError': onPlayerError
    }

    ...

    function onPlayerError(errorCode) {
         playnext();
    }

    ...
```