# Programmatically check if a youtube video link is valid?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically determine whether a Youtube video has been taken down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591293/programmatically-determine-whether-a-youtube-video-has-been-taken-down)

I want to check a list of links to Youtube videos (or Youtube id) to see if they are alive.
For example, I have a list of links that I would like to send to Youtube and check each for a response indicating whether or not the link points to a video.
I can check a link is alive or not, but I want to do it with a script.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591293/programmatically-determine-whether-a-youtube-video-has-been-taken-down?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you're on with PHP for doing this, try using `curl` with `curl_multi_init`

Initialize curl. `(curl_init, or curl_multi_init)`

Send multiple requests `(in multiple curl_exec calls if needed, or curl_multi_exec)`

Close curl. `(curl_close or curl_multi_close)`

So yes, all in one session

Comment: I thought of curl, but was unable to test it and checked if it worked.  Any chance you could be more specific?  Also, youtube has a dummy webpage in place if you go to a nonexistent video.  It would be a good idea to check to make sure there is a reasonable way to programmatically check for the success of the request (I hope you would be able to tell by looking at the http response, but I was unable to test that either and am not 100% sure it will be a reliable way of checking)