# Check if a video is available

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm working on YouTube data API v3.

I want to know how can i check if a video has been disabled or removed by YouTube.

E.g:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHt_6Z2OaZI

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=dHt_6Z2OaZI
&part=snippet,contentDetails,player,statistics,status
&key=[mykey]
```

I can not get any idea from the API.

```
{
"kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
"etag": "\"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/Y7032cCbQSAurzEiVMjdFYzamtg\"",
"pageInfo": {
"totalResults": 1,
"resultsPerPage": 1
},
"items": [
{
"kind": "youtube#video",
"etag": "\"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/2FORRsUGqbS1nvQK3AR1PfmiN7I\"",
"id": "dHt_6Z2OaZI",
"snippet": {},
"contentDetails": {
"duration": "PT1H31M1S",
"dimension": "2d",
"definition": "sd",
"caption": "false",
"licensedContent": false
},
"status": {
"uploadStatus": "processed",
"privacyStatus": "public",
"license": "youtube",
"embeddable": true,
"publicStatsViewable": true
},
"statistics": {
"viewCount": "301",
"likeCount": "0",
"dislikeCount": "0",
"favoriteCount": "0",
"commentCount": "0"
},
"player": {
"embedHtml": "<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/dHt_6Z2OaZI\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
}
}
]
}
```

I tried this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos
?part=id
&key=[mykey]
&id=dHt_6Z2OaZI
```

But it's NOT working, still give the result.

Comment: This question may have what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591293/programmatically-determine-whether-a-youtube-video-has-been-taken-down

Comment: @MC10 That question uses the deprecated v2 of the YouTube API, and is not helpful for anyone looking for an answer using the v3 API.

Comment: Relevant answer using v3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30197080/3417978

Answer (score 4):

There's a `status` field in the results you posted. I think the subfield that most closely relates to what you want is `uploadStatus`. When I perform an API call for that video, I get:

```
"status": {
    "uploadStatus": "rejected",
    "rejectionReason": "uploaderAccountSuspended",
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "license": "youtube",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicStatsViewable": true
   }
```

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.uploadStatus), here are the possible values for `uploadStatus`:

> - deleted
> - failed
> - processed
> - rejected
> - uploaded

After a video is successfully uploaded and processed, it should be accessible to users (assuming it's also public). Therefore, you should just be checking if status is "rejected" or "deleted".

Comment: I am afraid that does not work for deleted videos. This is what the api returns for a deleted video: {
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/q9wh51deRpP1b7X8Nc3D-bdBxqs\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 0
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still interested in this issue:

Right now ContentDetails of Item include RegionRestriction object. You have to analyze it to see if the video is available - here are the details: [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.regionRestriction)

Generally if RegionRestriction.Blocked contains a country you're viewing from, than the video is not available for you (similarly you can analyze RegionRestriction.Allowed).

Comment: Okay, but how do I check if video is removed by an author?